# how to detect iframe resize?

Tags: jquery, iframe, resize

i have a page with a function to resize the height of iframe in this page as a height of content of iframe but whene the iframe has a toggle action the height change and the function dosn't detect the resize of the iframe.
is there a way to detect if content of my iframe has change...

Answer (score 0):

Do both the parent document and the iframe have the same *origin*? If so, it is easier.

If not, you will need a workaround, that has been already discussed here in Stack Overflow.

It consists of including another iframe inside the iframe, that would point to a special url on the same domain as the top document. This way, the top document and the bottom-most iframe can communicate through JavaScript (since they have both the same origin). This is a *production* solution I use myself. Some big sites use it, Facebook is known to use (or to have used?) this.

Comment: This is something I am trying to do (the second solution you offer). Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

There is [this technique](http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Blog/post/2009/08/17/Another-Cross-Domain-iFrame-Communication-Technique.aspx) to communicate between iframes that [doesn't depend on timers](http://www.shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Examples/CrossDomain/ParentPage.html) which can be, as i've done recently, adapted to resizing of iframes based on the content of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 `setInterval(function() { your function}, 800);`
2 add a eventlistener to "onresize"
```

you can choose any one