# Is there any way to automatically resize an iframe if the size of the content inside changes?

Tags: dynamic, iframe, size

For example, I am trying to iframe the youtube subscription box on the homepage, and the problem is, if I make the iframe really long, then it wastes space, but if I make the size I want, then if the user clicks the "load more videos" button, then it gets cut off. So is there any way to make the iframe (or any alternatives) be a percentage of the size, or dynamically change when the page changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file and call it `iframe.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"></span>
    function autoIframe(frameId){
        try{
            frame = document.getElementById(frameId);
            innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument) ? frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;

            if (innerDoc == null){
                            // Google Chrome
                frame.height = document.all[frameId].clientHeight + document.all[frameId].offsetHeight + document.all[frameId].offsetTop;
            }
                    else{
                    objToResize = (frame.style) ? frame.style : frame;
                    objToResize.height = innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 18;
                    }
        }

        catch(err){
                alert('Err: ' + err.message);
            window.status = err.message;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="tree" name="tree" src="tree.html" onload="if (window.parent &amp;&amp; window.parent.autoIframe) {window.parent.autoIframe('tree');}"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Now create an html page called `tree.html` and put some dummy content in it.Make sure that the `iframe.html` and the `tree.html` are in the `same directory`. Open the `.html` files in browser and you will observe the o/p.

**Some more useful links :**

- [How to detect iframe resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088426/how-to-detect-iframe-resize)
- [How to detect iframe iframe resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286887/how-to-detect-iframe-iframe-resize)